# Laravel 7 database seed command not success

Tags: php, laravel

working with laravel 7 and using php artisan db:seed command to table seed. then in terminal displayed database seed succesfully message. but not data table filled with data. how could I fix this problem?
my existing database seedr.php file is

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should call your seeders classes in run function in DatabaseSeeder

Comment: Or call it in terminal with this command "php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder". Don't forgot to change UsersTableSeeder with your class

Comment: @MustafaHamdi may I need this type of class for other tables?

Comment: Make a seeder class foreach table and call all of them in run function in DatabaseSeeder

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple seeder class then use an array

```
 $this->call([
        CompaniesTableSeeder::class,
        DepartmentsTableSeeder::class
 ]);
```

Comment: in my seeder file I have booth seeder file like DatabaseSeeder.php and LaratrustSeeder.php Then how could I use seeders here

Comment: I have never used Laratrust before but based on the documentation, it works the same. Like this $this->call(LaratrustSeeder::class);